# IQueryable в Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Я так поняла, что если у меня данные IQueryable, то запрос выполняется, только когда я вызываю методы Count(), ToList() и подобные, либо начинаю перебирать в цикле.

```
//не загружает данные
IQueryable<Employees> employeesModels = _dbDopuskContext.Employees.AsNoTracking().Where(e => e.Deleted.Equals(0));

//не загружает данные    
foreach (string s in searchValues)
{
employeesModels = employeesModels.Where(e => e.Surname.Contains(s) || e.Name.Contains(s) || e.Patronymic.Contains(s) || e.Tabnum.Contains(s));
}                    

//загружает, т.к. используется Take
employeesModels = employeesModels.Skip((currentPage - 1) * Defined.EmployeesPageLength)
.Take(Defined.EmployeesPageLength);
```

В первый раз так и отрабатывает. Во второй после первого же простого запроса лист заполняется. Может бд хэш какой сохраняет? Она у меня все время подключена, как синглтон сделана.

Мне совершенно не подходит такой способ, надо запрос накопить и потом выполнить, у меня получается данные на клиенте сортируются.

Как сделать, чтобы данные заполнялись только когда я к ним обращаюсь?

Comment: Какой лист у вас заполняется и как вы это определили?

Comment: employeesModels, у него есть results. Я это вижу в дебаге.

Comment: нет у него results

Comment: Лучше смотрите фактически идущие к базе запросы в профилировщике, а не гадайте по приватным переменным.

Comment: База данных с EF конечно может сохранить данные и курсор с сопутствующим состоянием, но это еще не говорит о том, что вы действительно получаете фактические данные. Это надо смотреть на запросы, которые по факту приходят в БД с помощью профилировщика/мониторинга и работа дебаг версии от релиза так же может отличаться.

Comment: Меня смутило, что в ResultsView можно увидеть все мои записи из бд. Спасибо! Попробую.

Answer (score 6):

То, что вы видите в `ResultsView` в дебаге - это результат работы отладчика, который сам выполняет перечисление результатов. Фактически, запрос к базе выполняется каждый раз когда вы заглядываете в `ResultsView` - и к работе программы без отладчика это не имеет ни малейшего отношения.

Чтобы определить какие запросы к БД реально выполняются - нужно использовать профайлер.

Например, можно использовать встроенный в студию [IntelliTrace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd264915.aspx).

Альтернативный вариант - использовать утилиты идущие в составе с СУБД, например [SQL Server Profiler](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/tools/sql-server-profiler/sql-server-profiler)

Также можно использовать встроенные возможности Entity Framewwork в виде свойства [`DbContext.Database.Log`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dn221462(v=vs.113).aspx) - этот делегат будет вызываться каждый раз когда выполняется запрос к БД.

Comment: Спасибо! Хотела убедиться в правильной работе и студия сбила меня с толку. В понедельник попробую логи для очистки совести.